# Find records from one table which don't exist in another (total 3 tables)

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following three tables (in MySQL):

- Items
- Docs
- and links between items and docs

Items

| id | item | item_serial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item1 | 11111 |
| 2 | item2 | 22222 |
| 3 | item3 | 33333 |

Docs

| id | doc_# | doc_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | letter |
| 2 | 45 | act |
| 3 | 56 | contract |
| 4 | 98 | act |

Items_Docs

| id | item_id | doc_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 | 4 |

How do I find out which items do not have act (doc_type)?

The desired output would be:

| item_id |
| --- |
| 1 |

Thank you for help!

Comment: Have you tried using join operations?

Comment: Does item3 really have an act doc type?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use NOT EXISTS in this case. The table sizes and indexes could make this approach unworkable, but the OP didn't provide any table stats.

```
SELECT a.id
FROM Items a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT b.id
  FROM Docs b, Item_Docs c
  WHERE c.item_id = a.id
  AND b.id = c.Doc_id
  AND b.doc_type = 'act'
);
```